# Swift - iAd Banner on top of webView

Tags: ios, swift, webview

So I am loading a local HTML file into a webView with this code:

```
let localfilePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("countdown", withExtension: "html");
        let myRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: localfilePath!);
        countdownWebView.loadRequest(myRequest);
        self.view.addSubview(countdownWebView)
```

and am now trying to implement iAds with this standard line:

```
self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
```

However the iAd is appearing on top of my webView content, blocking part of it. Is there anything in my code that might suggest why the content is not resizing as it should be?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not spending time on this as iAd will discontinue on June 30th.

http://www.theverge.com/2016/1/15/10777496/apple-iad-app-shutdown-june-30th-confirmation

Comment: Thanks for making me aware of it. My app is for an event before that date so I should be ok for this on. Is adMob going to be the next best alternative for futures builds?

Comment: I'm not sure what the next best thing is but I think adMob is what most people use now.

Comment: Ah ok thanks. Will get some practice in with that for upcoming projects

Comment: @dwinnbrown Isn''t this answer an accepted solution to your question?

Comment: Well it didn't help me fix it so no don't think so.